# dynamic sql to dynamically create column name from field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

Here is my *Schema* :

**Table t1:**

```
 x1    y1
  1     2
```

**Table t2:**

```
 x2    y2
  1   'x1'
  2   'y2'
```

I need to use dynamic `SQL` to join these two tables and the join column of table t1 should be decided by the value of column *y2*.

I tried a very ugly and not-working SQL of cause of no use.

```
select * from t1 join t2 t on t2.x2 = t1.(select y2 from t2 where x2=t.x2);
```

I am very new to *dynamic* `SQL` so not sure how to achieve this.

**P.S. :** The values above are just for example. Actually, both the tables are dynamically created hence not necessary the column names will be same. Also, the column numbers may differ hence pivoting might not be that useful

Comment: I smell database design problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL, such more logic in the `on` clause:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2 t
     on t2.x2 = t1.x1 and t2.y2 = 'x1' or
        t2.x2 = t1.y1 and t2.y2 = 'y1';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. But both the tables are dynamically created hence not necessary the column names will be same. Also, the column numbers may differ hence pivoting might not be that useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is best handled at the program level (creating these dynamic queries).

You don't know the table names but it doesn't mean you can't create a store for the dynamic names (ie. another table, called "tables_meta" that contains a listing of all the dynamic tables).

Likewise, if you wanted a dynamic table to have dynamic fields as well, you could create a table to store the mapping between the dynamic table created and the associated dynamic fields ("fields_meta" containing a one to many association between table and its dynamic fields).

Querying the "meta" tables for table name and then building your query programmaticly using that retrieved name (and likewise fields) can allow you run any queries you want against the dynamic objects.

As for joining dynamic tables specifically, doing so assumes you have some insight into the fields that result in a meaningful join. If this is the case, you could create your dynamic tables, but with at least one static field with meaningful data, that would allow you to query your "tables_meta" for a table, then build a query in your program with that result to join your table X on its static field "join_here" with (repeat read from tables meta to get Y) and join it on Y."join_here" (the static field)

Very rough example sudo code:

```
List<String> sql-getDynamicTables = "select table_name from tables_meta";<br />
(results in X, Y, Z...)

if(sql-getDynamicTables.size > 1) { (make sure we have stuff to join on)
    (Start building the query for the join)
    String sql-performJoin = "select * from" + sql-getDynamicTables.get(0);

    for( each additional database found ) {
         sql-performJoin += " join " + sql-getDynamicTables.get(index-i) + " on " + sql-getDynamicTables.get(index-i)+".staticField = "(or replace that with a separate variable containing the dynamic field)+ sql-getDynamicTables.get(0)".staticField, ";
    }
    (remove any trailing commas)
    (add any where clause or whatever modifications to the query)
    (run the query sql-performJoin)
}
```

Again, column names might not be the same but you can query for them like we do the dynamic table names and build the query with that instead of ".staticField" or whatever you choose.

Just make sure you know that the data your joining on provides a meaningful join.

Just as a note: Dynamic SQL is quite painful and introduces a lot of considerations (duplicating table names, etc). It might be worth investigating alternatives if your still up in the air about it.